# How to set CSS/SCSS background-image property in Next JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am working on a project using React and Next JS, and this is a glimpse of the file structure:

```
// other root folders...
L pages
L public
L src
    L assets
        L image.svg // this is the image that I wanted to turn into a background of an element
    L components
L styles
  L divider.module.scss // this is where I've added the background-image property
```

I've successfully imported images using the syntax `import image from '[file path]'` with various extensions with a custom web pack configuration from the official documentation. The next.config.js consisted of the following:

```
module.exports = {
webpack: (config) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name]_[hash].[ext]',
      publicPath: `/_next/static/assets`,
      outputPath: 'static/assets',
    },
   });
    return config;
  },
};
```

However, the problem is that images that are loaded using CSS/SCSS seem to raise this particular error: `XML Parsing Error: syntax error export default "[file path]";`. Can anyone kindly elaborate what is it that I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You can install `next-images` plugin. But for me, you should move all assets into `/public`. Next will serve static file by default. Since version 10.0.0, Next.js has a built-in Image Component and Automatic Image Optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I don't have extensive experience with React JS but I've experimented with it a lot lately along with Webpack so I was hoping if there is something I could do to resolve this with a Webpack configuration because that's what's familiar so far for me. However, I'll attempt your suggestions. Also, is it convention to store all static files to this "public folder" in Next?

Comment: You can refer to https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving